# How to increase NVD3JS Pie-Chart label size

Tags: html, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I try to increase the label size of my nvd3js pie-chart, because it's really tiny. So I've read about doing this like this :

```
        <svg style="font: normal 28px Impact;"></svg>
```

or

```
        <div style="font: normal 28px Impact;">
            <svg></svg>
        </div>
```

But both ways don't change anything about my label size, have you maybe another solution to do this?

Complete code:

```
    <nvd3-pie-chart data="exampleData" id="exampleId" width="500" height="500" x="xFunction()" y="yFunction()" showLabels="true" labelType="percent">
        <div style="font: normal 28px Impact;">
            <svg></svg>
        </div>
    </nvd3-pie-chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do it :

> I prefer using **CSS**

```
.nv-label text{
    font-size:28px;
}
```

**using  JavaScript**

```
d3.select(".nv-label text").style("font-size","28px")
```